# Position an annotation to Y value in fusioncharts

Tags: javascript, fusioncharts

I need to position a line or rectangle in a given position for every category in a column chart. How can i position something in a position based on the Y axis values?
E.G. the Y axis has values from 0 to 1500, i want to position the first annotation line at 200.

Just to see what it should look like, this is the fiddle of the chart where i use some columns to position the annotation line (but then i can't hide those columns).
https://jsfiddle.net/21br83pz/

```
"annotations": {
    "showbelow": "0",
    //Annotations on a chart can be divided across multiple groups for easy management, and manipulation through API
    "groups": [{
      //Each group needs a unique ID
      "id": "Minimi",
      //Under each group, you can define multiple items. Each item is a polygon, text or image - with its own set of parameters.
      "items": [{
            //Each item needs a unique ID
            "id": "minimo-0",
            "type": "line",
            "fillColor": "#6baa01",
            "x": "$xaxis.0.label.0.startx",
            "y": "300",
            "tox": "$xaxis.0.label.0.endx"
        },{
            //Each item needs a unique ID
            "id": "minimo-1",
            "type": "line",
            "fillColor": "#6baa01",
            "x": "$xaxis.0.label.1.startx",
            "y": "300",
            "tox": "$xaxis.0.label.1.endx"
        },{
            //Each item needs a unique ID
            "id": "minimo-2",
            "type": "line",
            "fillColor": "#6baa01",
            "x": "$xaxis.0.label.2.startx",
            "y": "300",
            "tox": "$xaxis.0.label.2.endx"
        },
      ...
      ] // items
    }]
  }
```

Comment: didn't understand the problem. Could you please elaborate more.

Comment: I want to display a line (or a rectangle) at a given position in the Y axis different for every category/label on the X axis.
For example, let's say i have 3 products on my X axis:
-pokeball
-megaball
-ultraball
I have many values (columns) for every product (how much it sells on every region). I need to draw a line for the minimum i wanted it to sell, different for every product.
I posted my code which used a column to set the line position, but i can't hide the column afterwards (i don't want that column to be shown). If there's a way to do it without the column trick, even better.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the y coordinate of the starting position of the annotation for the topmost position (taken as zero) of the chart using the y attribute.
Specify the x coordinate of the ending position of the annotation for the leftmost position (taken as zero) of the chart, using the toX attribute.

```
    {
    "chart": {
        ...
    },
    "data": [{
        ...
    }],
    "annotations": {
            ...
        "groups": [{
            "items": [{
                "id": "dyn-labelBG",
                "type": "rectangle",
                "radius": "3",
                "x": "290",
                "y": "60",
                "tox": "390",
                "toy": "90",
                "color": "#0075c2",
                "alpha": "70",
                "origW": "400",
                "origH": "300"
            }]
        }]
    }
}
```

To know more about this feature please refer - https://www.fusioncharts.com/dev/chart-guide/chart-configurations/annotations/positioning-annotations-using-absolute-values

https://www.fusioncharts.com/dev/chart-guide/chart-configurations/annotations/positioning-annotations-using-macros

Here is the demo fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/fusioncharts/ufgt8a10/

Hope this would help.